# dplyr group_by acts like arrange, why?

Tags: r, dplyr

Sorry but I tried to search on my topic question but I couldn't find an answer, maybe it's too basic. Apologies if this is too newbie.

I am trying to group by my `DF` by `VisitNumber` column. I only get arranged by like this :

```
   TripType VisitNumber Weekday
      (int)       (int)  (fctr)
1       999           5  Friday
2        30           7  Friday
3        30           7  Friday
4        26           8  Friday
5        26           8  Friday
6        26           8  Friday
7        26           8  Friday
```

I would like to get :

```
Count   TripType VisitNumber Weekday
       (int)       (int)  (fctr)
1       999           5  Friday
2        30           7  Friday
4        26           8  Friday
```

I wrote this code :

```
train%>%
  select(TripType,VisitNumber,Weekday)%>%
  group_by(VisitNumber)
```

Comment: You've grouped by `VisitNumber` - that doesn't apply any function to each group. You need something to apply to the other variables. Are you taking the first value of the remaining variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is a rather gimmicky way to do it, but here you go:

```
TripType <- c(999, 30, 30, 26, 26, 26, 26)
VisitNumber <- c(5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8)
Weekday <- rep('Friday', 7)

data <- data.frame(TripType, VisitNumber, Weekday)

count <- table(VisitNumber)
data <- data.frame(unique(data), count)
data$VisitNumber.1 <- NULL

data
##   TripType VisitNumber Weekday Freq
##1      999           5  Friday    1
##2       30           7  Friday    2
##4       26           8  Friday    4
```

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ VisitNumber, data, FUN=head, 1)` or `data[by(seq_len(nrow(data)), data$VisitNumber, FUN=head,1),]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys, I have found a solution.

I used this code instead :

```
train%>%
  select(TripType,VisitNumber,Weekday)%>%
  group_by(TripType,VisitNumber,Weekday)%>%
  summarise(count=n())
```

Regards,